# Copy array word-by-word vs letter-by-letter

Tags: c

I am currently using the following way to copy an array of strings:

```
void copy_sentinel_array(char ** buffer, char ** list) {
    while (*list) {
        *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(*list) + 1);
        *buffer++ = *list++;
    }
    *buffer = NULL;
    return;
}
```

It's simple enough and works fine. However, I'm having more trouble doing the same thing copying the words over letter by letter (so I can, for example, upper or lowercase the letters). For example:

```
void copy_sentinel_array(char ** buffer, char ** list) {
    while (*list) {
        *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(*list) + );
        for (int i=0; i<=strlen(*list); i++)
            (*buffer)[i] = tolower((*list)[i]); // let's lowercase it
        buffer++;
        list++;
    }
    *buffer = NULL;
    return;
}
```

What would be the proper way to do this copy per-word and then per-letter?

Comment: The first version has a memory leak. It's allocating memory, and then replacing the pointer with the original pointer from `list`. It's not copying the strings, just copying the pointers.

Comment: @Barmar -- so it should be: `memcpy (*buffer++, *list++, strlen(*list))` instead? If so, could you please explain what I'm doing wrong in an answer vs. what should be done and I'll accept that?

Comment: The code in your last comment is wrong. The function strlen returns the length of the string without the terminating null character. If you use memcpy, you must not forget to add (or copy) the terminating null character. If you use strcpy instead of memcpy, it will be added automatically.

Comment: Questions are getting better -- good job.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you for the encouragement!

Comment: Note that `memcpy (*buffer++, *list++, strlen(*list))` is undefined -- the increment from `*list++` might happen before or after `strlen(*list)`...

Comment: @TagC198 is there any reason you are not simply passing `list` as the parameter and then returning `char **` from `copy_sentinel_array`? Example [C - Copy List w/Sentinel NULL](https://pastebin.com/qTwFLmd3) As it sits you must allocate pointers elsewhere for `buffer`. May as well do that all in one function.

Comment: @ChrisDodd in that case, would `strcpy(*buffer++, *list++)` also be undefined, or does that issue not exist because there is no third argument?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for posting that's very helpful -- out of curiosity why do you use `calloc` and then `malloc` five lines below it? Why not malloc both times?

Comment: `calloc` is to allocate the pointers setting all bytes zero so your pointers are all `NULL` (since we are using a sentinel `NULL` to mark the end of the words) `malloc` is used to allocate storage for each string. No benefit to setting each character zero `:)` You could use `malloc` for both since we also ensure there is an explicit `NULL` written at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. `*buffer[i]` is equivalent to `*(buffer[i])`, but what you want is `(*buffer)[i]` (and the same for `list`).

If you don't need to process each character you can just use

```
strcpy(*buffer, *list);
```

Comment: thanks for this. What's the difference between doing `memcpy` and `strcpy`?

Comment: `strcpy()` automatically stops at the null terminator, so you don't have to get the length first.

Comment: You forgot the `+1` for the null byte in your `memcpy()` call. `strcpy()` won't make that mistake.